# What is the meaning of the word “finesse” in an aviation context?

Tags: sens, terminologie

I came across this question in a theory exam.
Can anyone tell me the meaning of the word FINESSE in this context.

> À la *FINESSE* maximum :
>
> 1. votre taux de chute est minimum et votre angle de plané est maximum
> 2. votre taux de chute est minimum
> 3. votre angle de plané et votre taux de chute sont minimum
> 4. votre angle de plané est minimum

I also found another occurence of the word somewhere else.

> Le vent effectif se manifeste par les effets de variations de vitesse ou de FINESSE par rapport au sol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finesse in this context is an aerodynamic property corresponding to the lift-to-drag ratio (rapport portance/traînée in french).

Comment: [_Finesse aérodynamique_](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8397354)(GDT).